# Remove orphan jobs - Event ID 8031 - SP2013

Tags: 2013, search, timer-jobs, stsadm

I deleted two times the search service application and recreated it a third time.

Now every 15 minutes I see an error with event ID 8031 in my eventvwr, I can get the ID of the objet associated with the missing application via SQL.

But the command below is not available

```
Stsadm -o deleteconfigurationobject -Id <ID>
```

How can I delete those 2 objects in SharePoint 2013 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked below given link for the same issue which you are having?

[Eventid 8031 visible every 15 minutes](https://spcandoit.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/eventid-8031-visible-every-15-minutes/)

It is mentioned over there that you should use

```
STSADM -o deleteconfigurationobject -id <ColumnID>
```

I am not sure whether it works for you or not.

Please let me know if it not works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, as I said the option deleteconfigurationobject from stsadm command is not available ....

Comment: Do you have an access to run stsadm commands?

Comment: Yes, I can run stsadm but when I run "stsadm -help" I can't see deleteconfigurationobject....

Comment: Can you please provide me an error (if you get) while performing this?

Comment: As sometimes hyphen (-) creating the problem if it is pasted from some other place.

Comment: is that works works for you?

Comment: Well it turns out deleteconfigurationobject is not listed when you list all options for stsadm but it worked perfectly.